# PHP: sticky checkbox with default state checked

Tags: php, sticky

I'm using PHP to show only selected records from a MySQL table. There's a form with a submit button so the user can refine their search ("Show only records where fieldX = valueY"...)

To make the form sticky I've used this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="SBS" value="SBS" <?php if($_POST['SBS'] == 'SBS') echo'checked="checked" ' ?> />
```

The only problem is that I need the default value to be checked. I tried adding

```
$_POST['SBS'] = 'SBS';
```

at the top, but this obviously sets the variable every time the form is submitted, so I can't turn it off!

Thanks

Comment: _To make the form sticky, I've used this code:_, um we are talking about the checkbox are we? Does this mean the checkbox has to always be checked and the user cannot uncheck it? In other words, please define _sticky_ in your use and also the _how_ and _when_ this checkbox should be checked by default

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. The checkbox needed to retain it's value when the form was submitted and the page reloaded. It should be checked as default on initial page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set `$_POST['SBS']`. Let the submit of the form do that.

If you want to default the checkbox to ticked, then you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to detect a `GET` or a `POST`.

This will use the `$_POST` if the form has been submitted, otherwise if it is a `GET`, it will default to checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="SBS" value="SBS" <?php if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['SBS'] == 'SBS') || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') echo'checked="checked" ' ?> />
```

You could also use `$_REQUEST['SBS']` instead of `$_POST['SBS']` to default the value from the `POST` or from the query string, via a `GET`.

Comment: @MarkButler, no problem. If the answer helped, feel free to upvote it, and perhaps even mark it as the accepted answer, when you can.

Comment: I accepted it, but apparently need more reputation before I can upvote.